# Creative uses of WordPress

Tags: customization

As WordPress grows, it becomes possible to make more and more sites using the technology. Pages and the permalink structure give it CMS power, custom taxonomies and post types expand this further to differentiate chronological posts, pages and arbitrary objects, and plugins fill the gaps.

So, you can use WP to power your blog, photo gallery, and website. What are some of the more creative uses you've seen that exploit powerful WordPress features? What are some sites that made you say, "*That's* WordPress?"

Comment: a similar question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85/how-can-you-use-custom-types-taxonomies

Answer (score 5):

## Contact Manager

http://rolopress.com/

Organize contacts and companies… your way.

- Easily enter and modify contacts and companies
- Keep track of phone numbers, email addresses, websites, social networks and many other types of information.
- Create your own Themes.
- Add functionality by installing Plugins. (or write your own)

(replaced by piklist crm http://piklist.com )

Comment: Plugin is outdated and not longer supported

Answer (score 4):

Just Tell Me Why

http://justtellmewhy.com/

A Web 2.0 platform for debates...

Answer (score 3):

Using WP as a forum

http://thedeadone.net/download/tdo-forum-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at http://wordpress.org/showcase/ ?

There's a **ton** of "that's WordPress?!" sites there.

Answer (score 3):

I also found:

#### WordPress as a QA site

http://wordpressqa.com/

#### WordPress as a Ticketing system

http://getqualitycontrol.com/

Answer (score 2):

Although these examples may not be surprising to long-time WordPress users, new users may find them interesting, so I figured I'd list them. I sometimes use such examples with clients who are unsure of WordPress.

**Ecommerce Sites**

- http://www.teesey.com/
- https://threeminuteegg.com/
- http://wallsticker.ro/

(I pulled these particular examples from the [Shopp](http://shopplugin.net/) plugin. There's also the [WP e-Commerce](http://www.instinct.co.nz/e-commerce/) plugin, for those who are interested.)

**Social Networking Sites**

- http://pro.gigaom.com/
- http://tdi.vw.com/leaderboard/
- http://thepioneerwoman.com/tasty-kitchen/

(These are powered by [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/), which sits on top of WordPress. I've also heard of the [Mingle](http://blairwilliams.com/mingle-wordpress-plugin/) plugin, which supposedly does something similar, but have never tried it.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one from a local record company (Portland, OR).

http://saphurecords.com/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

As a product display website for a small business. For instance, with [this site](http://doubleabody.com/), I composed it with the [PODS plugin](http://podscms.org/) and a custom theme I designed myself.

Answer (score 0):

[**How can WordPress be used, besides a blog?**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/783/how-can-wordpress-be-used-besides-a-blog/1482#1482)

A similar quesiton at web masters